# java read file from network device

Tags: java, file, networking, io

Can someone help me to find a tutorial or sample java code to

read a file from any machine which is in the same network

Comment: How do you want to access the file? HTTP? NFS? Samba? FTP?

Answer (score 25):

The simplest way to do this would be to read it using regular file paths.

On Windows:

```
new File("\\\\server\\path\\to\\file.txt")
// (double-backslashes required for backslashes in path)
```

On Unix:

First mount the share using Samba (SMB, NFS or whatever other protocol) to some location like /mnt/network. Then you can use:

```
new File("/mnt/network/path/to/file.txt")
```

Once you have the File object you can use FileInputStream, FileReader or whatever else you want to read the file in.

*Edit* for comments response. If you are using an Applet, you probably want to pull the file from a web server. You can use the built in java.net.URL class but I would recommend this if you have to do more than just simple stuff: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/index.html

Example (from the Commons HTTP Site):

```
    // Create an instance of HttpClient.
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    // Create a method instance.
    GetMethod method = new GetMethod(url);

    try {
      // Execute the method.
      int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);

      if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        System.err.println("Method failed: " + method.getStatusLine());
      }

      // Read the response body.
      byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();

      // Deal with the response.
      // Use caution: ensure correct character encoding and is not binary data
      System.out.println(new String(responseBody));

    } catch (HttpException e) {
      System.err.println("Fatal protocol violation: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Fatal transport error: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      // Release the connection.
      method.releaseConnection();
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: in this case do i need to sign applet ?

Comment: and i should use shared folder without mounting like ip://folder , do you think java new File("ip//folder/file") is meaningfull

Comment: Is there a solution on Linux that doesn't require mounting the share?  I don't have permission to use the mount command, and if I try to use the Windows solution, it creates a file in the local directory with slashes in the name.

Answer (score 0):

This is not that simple! To use Server Client Aplications you need a Network API.
I have 1 by DeBukkit and an extended version. If you would to send Files I will suggest my one (Server Client Extended .jar) becazse there is an Option to send Files (FilePacket.java).
This are the links to the libs: [All Libs](http://5.230.12.26:8080/YouTube/?page=libs)

Code for Server for Client Server Extended:

```
public class TestServer extends Server {

    public TestServer() {
        super(29898, true, true,true);
        registerMethod("bt", new FileReciver() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleteRecive(FileInfo data) {
                System.out.println("Completely recived : "+data);
                Path p = Paths.get(data.getName());
                try {
                    Files.createFile(p);
                    Files.write(p, data.getContent());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
             /**
             * @see com.bebukkit.niton.network.packets.buffer.BufferedPacketReciver#run(com.bebukkit.niton.network.packets.Packet, java.net.Socket)
             */
            @Override
            public void run(Packet<? extends Serializable> msg, Socket socket) {
                super.run(msg, socket);
                sendMessage(new Packet<Boolean>("", null), socket);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void preStart() 
    {
        registerMethod("msg", new ReciveMethod() {

            @Override
            public void run(Packet<? extends Serializable> msg, Socket socket) {
                broadcastMessage(msg);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onWrongDataPacketException(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivePacketError(IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPacketReckognized(ServerSocket socket) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPacketSendException(Exception e, Packet<? extends Serializable> message, Socket socket2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSendPacketToNotConnectedClient(Packet<? extends Serializable> message, Socket socket2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onBrodcast(Packet<? extends Serializable> pack) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onServerStartError(IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onServerStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Code for Client:

```
package com.bebukkit.niton.network.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.bebukkit.niton.network.Client;
import com.bebukkit.niton.network.packets.Packet;
import com.bebukkit.niton.network.packets.ReciveMethod;

public class TestClient extends Client {

    public TestClient() {
        super("localhost", 29898, 5000, false,true);
        registerMethod("msg", new ReciveMethod() {

            @Override
            public void run(Packet<? extends Serializable> msg, Socket socket) {
                System.out.println(msg.getData());
            }
        });
        registerMethod("replay", new ReciveMethod() {

            @Override
            public void run(Packet<? extends Serializable> msg, Socket socket) {
                System.out.println("REREplay");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onSocketClosingFail() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginPacketSendingFailed(IOException ex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionError(IOException ex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReciveError(Exception ex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPacketSendError(Exception ex, Packet<? extends Serializable> pack) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
    }

}
```

You need a seperated Server + Client Starter:

```
package com.bebukkit.niton.network.test;

public class ServerStarter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestServer();
    }

}
```

Client:

```
package com.bebukkit.niton.network.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

import com.bebukkit.niton.network.packets.Packet;
import com.bebukkit.niton.network.packets.buffer.BufferedPacket;
import com.bebukkit.niton.network.packets.file.FileInfo;
import com.bebukkit.niton.network.packets.file.FilePacket;

public class ClientStarter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        TestClient tc = new TestClient();
        tc.start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override   
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                JFileChooser c = new JFileChooser("Choose a file to upload");
                c.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
                c.showDialog(null,"Upload");
                File f = c.getSelectedFile();
                try {
                    tc.sendMessage(new FilePacket("file", f));
                    tc.sendMessage(new Packet<String>("replay","test"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file path in a different pc (*i.e.* Network devices) but connected to the same **LAN**, then you can easily access it by using these 2 steps.

**Step 1:** you need to map the network drive (i.e. your desired folder) into a physical drive, for example:
In Windows, `\\10.221.222.6/some/path/of/images` path mapped into a Drive like `Z:\ or Y:\`

**Step 2:**

```java
String externalSharedFilePath = "file:Z:/images/";

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations(externalSharedFilePath);

}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try the following URL for a tutorial http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/construct_file_name_path.shtml

I think the best way is to use `java.net.URL` to open a InputSteam, because you can generalize it to files, that are not necessarily on the same network.