# Access shared resources on a remote machine on LAN

Tags: java, network-programming

I am looking for API's or existing classes which help me access shared resources over LAN.
I want to read files from the remote machine and copy it on the local machine.

Have considered few API's but could not be used due to platform dependency
[JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/)

Any help/suggestions on the same would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any reasons why you don't want to use the java standard IO library (which enables you to read, write, copy files etc. on network locations)?

Comment: I am not able to access resource on a remote machine using the standard IO library.

Comment: `File f = new File("file://///etp-05-149/Projects/Issues.xls");
 System.out.println(f.length());`

Comment: This prints the file size as 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved using [Commons VFS API](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/)
The `org.apache.commons.vfs2` package can be used to access resources on a remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
File f = new File("//etp-05-149/Projects/Issues.xls");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Take a look a this, shows ways to read file from shared resourec/network
```

[java-read-file-from-network-device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682194/java-read-file-from-network-device)