# Java open file on shared location

Tags: java, file-io, applet

I want to do something like this:

File root = new File("C:/file.txt");

but on a folder which is shared on a local network. So lets say the file is on 192.168.1.28 how make it with above command?

Next not working:

`File root = new File("//192.168.1.2/file.txt");`

`File root = new File("\\\\192.168.1.2/file.txt");`

`File root = new File("\\192.168.1.2/file.txt");`

`File root = new File("file:\\192.168.1.2/file.txt");`

`File root = new File("file://192.168.1.2/file.txt");`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think its possible that java just don't work with networked files like this. Solution would be to copy the file over first then open in java

Comment: What does this have to do with applets?  Can you do it from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible.  However you need to first mount the share using for example Samba - more info here - [java read file from network device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682194/java-read-file-from-network-device)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/). It is a library that allow you to manipulate files on various kind of filesystem, one of them perfectly suited for your need is the CIFS file system:

> Provides access to the files on a CIFS server, such as a Samba server,
>   or a Windows share.
>
> URI Format
>
> smb://[ username[: password]@] hostname[: port][ absolute-path]
>
> Examples
>
> ```
> smb://somehost/home
> ```

The provider for CIFS file system is still in development, but you can give it a try. 
I've already used the library to give transparent access to files via http and ftp protocols.

Answer (score 0):

Java alone doesn't have support for  networked file sharing, as the code you're supplying is trying to do.

But if you use a library, like [Samba](http://jcifs.samba.org/), then you can. But it would be different than the code you showed.

[java read file from network device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682194/java-read-file-from-network-device)

Answer (score 0):

Java just don't support networked file sharing

Answer (score 0):

With Java 1.8, you can use Java to access files on shared location. Let's say you want to access a .xls file called (Sample.xls) on a shared location.

```
String location = "\\\your.shared.location.company.com\\folder1\\folder2\\";
String fileName = "Sample.xls";
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(location + fileName);
```