# Can't access Network folders through Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a .war file published on Apache Tomcat 7.0. The application accesses a folder and displays the filenames of the files inside. This is working perfectly when the folder is on the local machine. However when the folder in on the Network server (accessed through \\192.168.x.xx\foldername) then the application can't access it and displays "No files found").

We've tried searching for a possible solution but didn't find anything that seemed related to this specific issue. We also tried the usual solutions like granting access (sharing), running the application as Administrator, even checking Tomcat users settings but nothing worked. So my question is, what do we need to do to allow the application to access that network folder. I also should mention that when the application is running from Eclipse, it can access the folder without any problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Tomcat. For one, `\\host\share` is the Windows-specific way to access a CIFS/SMB share from an Explorer window; it won't work on *nix where you have to mount the share to a directory. If you're willing to change the code in the war, take a look at [Java open file on shared location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356849/java-open-file-on-shared-location) or at JCIFS. Or if you map the share to a network drive, you can do `z:\...`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The directory is dynamic so if the user is on a *nix system, they'll give the appropriate path. Changing the code isn't an issue but I want to make sure it's necessary in my case. As I mentioned, reading the files works as it should when run from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can trick it out by modifying the service properties **not** to use Local System account and explicitly put the account that already has privilege. (even though you are already logged in using it)

I hope it helps.