# Java Web Application Image Transfer

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss

Using Tomcat or JBoss, how do I transfer and save dynamic image content from an image repository on one server to a number of other servers (machines) on the same network without writing a Client/Server application?
The web site I am building contains a large number of images that will only be saved and shared on one machine.  All of the web app servers need to be able to access these files.

Comment: I wouldn't do that but things might become subjective. Have you considered alternative solutions like using a NAS (or shared directory) or other solutions ?

Comment: I have not considered NAS.  What are my options in this context using Java?  FYI, I am developing this application on a Windows 2019 Server.

Comment: There are multiple unperfect options but like I said, it could become very subjective. Do you have specific requirements ?

Comment: I have to keep costs down i.e. I need to use the Windows OS services.  Each web response will need to access these image files which are over 400 GBs in size and cannot be stored on a number of machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kermit Love, here are a few suggestions based on your requirements. Note that none of these are based on Java nor specific to Tomcat / JBoss.

**Option 1 : Using a NAS or a Shared Directory**

Using a specific hardware (NAS), a file server (Samba) or a simple shared directory over the network would allow all you machines to access the content through the network.

**Pros**:

- This solution can scale
- Setup is easy

**Cons**:

- The network overhead may slow down your global solution depending on your needs (access frequency, images sizes, ...)
- No high-availability (fault tolerance)

**Option 2 : Using an upfront server dedicated to load balancing / reverse-proxy / serving files**

You can use a simple Nginx / Apache server to deliver "static" content while routing trafic to your application servers.

**Pros:**

- Efficient way to serve images to clients.
- You separate the concerns (business logic vs serving files).

**Cons:** No high-availability (fault tolerance)

**Option 3 : Using `rsync` to synchronise file systems**

You can define a `cron` based rule to run a rsync command every N seconds/minutes to ensure all your machines have the data available.

**Pros:**

- Easy to setup
- Free (no need extra hardware, for now)
- (slightly) better performance in the long term than option 1 (no repeated network overhead).

**Cons:**

- Yet an extra-process
- Doesn't scale horizontally
- Files won't be immediately accessible

Comment: Thanks for this information but I think the following post addresses my needs:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356849/java-open-file-on-shared-location

Comment: Cool that was the first option. Feel free to read my Pros / Cons anyway :)