# Load image from a network drive?

Tags: java, image, swing, imageicon

My workstation is running windows, and we develop Java Applications that run on windows. On these windows desktops we have access to our shared network drive. So I need to load an image from the network drive, but it doesn't work. Am I doing this wrong?

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class LoadImage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try  {
            Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("\\\\networkdive\\folderonnetwork\\image.jpg");  
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "", "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, new ImageIcon(image));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are encountering significant network latency, you can defer the loading to an instance of `SwingWorker`, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4530659/230513).

Note that the example uses `ImageIO.read()` rather than [`Toolkit#getImage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getImage%28java.lang.String%29), which "may still contain stale information which was loaded from the file after a prior call."

Comment: I did this: `Image image = ImageIO.read(new URL("//NetworkDrive/Folder/image.jpg"));` and I got the error, "java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: //NetworkDrive/Folder/image.jpg"

Comment: What not use `new File()`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1682450/230513)?

Comment: @chudapati09 try new File("\\\\networkdrive\\folder\\image.jpg") the path you tried to use is not a valid URL, urls should start with a protocol identifier. I've just spent the last week writing a picture API to read pictures off network drives this way & this works just fine

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a Samba/CIFS path is a valid URL or a local file. Have a look at [JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/) instead.

Comment: Interesting. On my platform Samba/CIFS shares appear under a mount point named `/Volumes/`. Is there nothing similar on Windows?

Comment: Yes, on Windows you can map a share to a drive letter, say `U:`. Files can then be accessed from Java using `new File("u:/filename.txt)`. Requires OS level user interaction though (just like mounting on Unix).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense; JCIFS would allow programatic access to the share. +1 and thanks for the explication.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found this through Google. I resolved this issue by using "file:\\\\" ahead of the samba url.