# How to find the shared directory folder with greater size and email it

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Is it possible to write a java program which finds the folder with greater size and email it to someone?

Is it possible to check the size of a shared directory on local system? I want to check a local shared directory.

I have a program which checks the size of a local directory like

```
C:, D: etc..
```

But I need to find the size of a folder inside a shared resource server which starts with some numbered address like ://172.34.56.23/BDRD/GFTR...

Comment: Have you tried `new File("\\\\172.34.56.23\\BDRD\\GFTR\\...")` as mentioned in [java read file from network device](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1682194/851811) ?

Comment: Ya.. It worked with the 4 black slashes in the file path.. thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [UNC network path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#UNC_in_Windows), such as `\\172.34.56.23\BDRD\GFTR\...`.

Take into account the backslash (`\`) character is an escape character, so you'll need to use double backslashes (`\\`) to make the compiler understand you want the `\` literal:

Try `new File("\\\\172.34.56.23\\BDRD\\GFTR\\...")`, as suggested in [java read file from network device](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1682194/851811).