# Spring - extract files from NAS folder

Tags: spring, file, spring-integration, nas

I'm trying to pull some files from a NAS (Linux) to local machine by using Spring.

I'd like not to use SFTP session in Spring even it works... in fact I used to pull files from an sftp server but due to some reason now the only resource I have is this NAS.

Is there any way to get it worked ? Or I have to write my own class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from here [java read file from network device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682194/java-read-file-from-network-device):

> The simplest way to do this would be to read it using regular file paths.
>
> On Windows:
>
> ```
> new File("\\\\server\\path\\to\\file.txt")
> // (double-backslashes required for backslashes in path)
> ```
>
> On Unix:
>
> First mount the share using Samba (SMB, NFS or whatever other protocol) to some location like `/mnt/network`. Then you can use:
>
> ```
> new File("/mnt/network/path/to/file.txt")
> ```
>
> Once you have the File object you can use `FileInputStream`, `FileReader` or whatever else you want to read the file in.

As far as you are able to mount the remote shared dir to the local filesystem you can easily start to use regular Spring Integration:

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter channel="files"
                directory="/mnt/network/path/to/">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="10000"/>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Comment: What is the condition to use `new File("/mnt/network/path/to/file.txt")` ? Because the location of my files are accessible with credentiels, not sure how to do in this case.

Comment: I think that should be done on OS level via user permissions to that mounted remote disk.

Comment: I tried this line `File f = new File("/mnt/network/path/to/file.txt");` but when I evaluated expression `f.getAbsolutePath()` what I got is a path under my project root like `C:/projects/project1/mnt/network/path/to/file.txt` while it does not exist.

Comment: Well, you are on Windows and you don't follow its style: `new File("\\\\server\\path\\to\\file.txt")` ?

Comment: Oh I thought the NAS was on Linux so I used `new File("/mnt/network/path/to/file.txt")`... problem solved, thanks !